# Unable to instantiate class load helper class: org.quartz.simpl.CascadingClassLoadHelper cannot be cast to org.quartz.spi.ClassLoadHelper error

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, quartz-scheduler, classcastexception

I am migrating my application from JBoss 5 to Wildfly 21.0.1.Final. I deployed an ear file containing a war and a jar module on Wildfly. During server startup I see the following error

```
02:56:03,956 INFO  [com.xis.framework.batch.service.scheduler.QuartzScheluder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 114)  START :: com.xis.framework.batch.service.scheduler.QuartzScheluder.getSchduler()
02:56:03,967 ERROR [com.xis.framework.batch.service.scheduler.QuartzScheluder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 114) **Error occured while getting the schduler object: org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Unable to instantiate class load helper class: org.quartz.simpl.CascadingClassLoadHelper cannot be cast to org.quartz.spi.ClassLoadHelper [See nested exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.quartz.simpl.CascadingClassLoadHelper cannot be cast to org.quartz.spi.ClassLoadHelper**
  at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:538)
        at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1094)
        at com.xiss.framework.batch.service.scheduler.QuartzScheluder.getSchduler(QuartzScheluder.java:68)
        at com.xis.framework.batch.service.scheduler.QuartzScheluder.processJobs(QuartzScheluder.java:40)
        at com.xis.framework.batch.service.scheduler.QuartzInitializerListener.contextInitialized(QuartzInitializerListener.java:99)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:219)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
```

QuartzScheluder.java

```
            if (jobDetails != null && jobDetails.size() != 0) {
                Scheduler scheduler = getSchduler();  --->Error at this line
                for (QuartzJobDetail jobDet : jobDetails) {     
                    processSchduler(jobDet, scheduler);
                }
            private static Scheduler getSchduler() {
        if(logger.isInfoEnabled()){
            logger.info(" START :: "+ QuartzScheluder.class.getName()  +".getSchduler()");
        }
        SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler scheduler = null;
        try {
            scheduler = sf.getScheduler();
            scheduler.start();
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            logger.error("Error occured while getting the schduler object", e);
        }
        if(logger.isInfoEnabled()){
            logger.info(" END :: "+ QuartzScheluder.class.getName()  +".getSchduler()");
        }
        return scheduler;
    }
```

Using the quartz.properties" file (as a resource) located  in the org/quartz package

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = DefaultQuartzScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export = false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy = false
org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction = false
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```

My ear pom.xml has the following dependency

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Anyone else had this issue and what can be done to resolve this?

Comment: Have you looked at migrating to the `ManagedExecutorService` rather than Quartz?

Comment: These kinds of errors are typically caused by multiple identical or different versions of dependency JARs on your application's classpath. Please check and make sure your application does not contain multiple quartz JARs (in WEB-INF/lib or elsewhere), or does not use the shared Quartz WildFly module.BTW: quartz 1.6.3 is a very ancient (year 2008) version of Quartz, please consider using a new version.

Comment: @JanMoravec  Quartz jar is present in both ear and war. I have removed jar from WEB-INF/lib of war and it worked. Thanks

Comment: This is how I excluded the jar in pom.xml                                                              
                                                                                                                      
                    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.6</version>
       <configuration>
           <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/quartz- 
                                                   1.5.0.jar</packagingExcludes>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>